# how to request getparameter for hidden input in mulitpart in servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload

I have hidden input type where i had stored selected id

**JSP File**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="./PropertyImage">
    <input type="hidden" name="property_id" value="<%=bean.getproperty_id%>"/>
</form>
```

now in servlet i had to access this hidden input type

**Sevlet**

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

    // Create a new file upload handler
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload( factory );
    // upload.setSizeMax(yourMaxRequestSize);

    // Parse the request
    List<FileItem> uploadItems;

try
    {
        uploadItems = upload.parseRequest( request );

        Dictionary dict = new Hashtable();

        for( FileItem uploadItem : uploadItems )
        {
          if( uploadItem.isFormField() )
          {  
              String fname = "";
              String fieldName = uploadItem.getFieldName();
              String value = uploadItem.getString();

            dict.put(fieldName, value);
          }       
            System.out.println("Property  id == "+dict.get("property_id"));

        final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY="E:/parag/project/New folder/sam/WebContent/images/agentimg";

        String image_name="";
        String imagepath="";

        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
        {
            try 
            {
                for(FileItem item : uploadItems)
                {
                    if(!item.isFormField())
                    {
                        //get the value for select images to upload . 
                        image_name = new File(item.getName()).getName();

                        System.out.println("image name == "+image_name);
                        String imagename=new Date().getTime()+image_name;
                        item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator +imagename));
                        request.setAttribute("image", UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + image_name);

                        //create images path to forward database.
                        imagepath="images/agentsimg/"+imagename;

                        System.out.println("path == "+imagepath);
                    }
                }

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            PropertyBean bean = new PropertyBean();

//              bean.setProperty_id(property_id);
            bean.setProperty_image(imagepath);

            int status = PropertyModel.propertyImage(bean);

            if(status>0)
            {  
                String message = "Image added to database";
                request.setAttribute("message", message);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/properties.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            else
            {  
                String message1 = "Image not added to database";
                request.setAttribute("message1", message1);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/properties.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }  

        }
        else
        {
            String message2 = "Image upload to database";
            request.setAttribute("message2", message2);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/agents.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but the output is

> Property id == null

please help me this

how to get request parameter of hidden input type while multipart???

Answer (score 0):

Firstly whatever you are doing is completely wrong...

If you are encrypting your form fields with `multipart/form-data` then you need to parse your request should be decrypted on the servlet side.

For that first you need `common-io-version.jar` and `commons-fileupload-version.jar`

then in you **`Servlet`** just put code below and you will be done with it....

```
if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
    {

        try
        {
            List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

            for (FileItem item : multiparts)
            {
                //check if the item that we get is a file or just a form data 
                //go in if condition if file found else goto else for form data
                if (!item.isFormField())
                {
                    //gets the file name from request
                    String name = item.getName();

                    // At the place of UPLOAD_DIRECTORY you can replace your path to the folder where you want to save your image
                    File userdir = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY);

                    //create user directory if not exists
                    if (!userdir.exists())
                    {
                        userdir.mkdir();
                    }
                    boolean exist=true;

                    String photoURL=UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name;
                    File photo=new File(photoURL);
                    item.write(photo);
                    System.out.println("Photo Number"+number);

                }
                else
                {
                    // Here you will get each and every field that you defined within your form tag
                    String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                    String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                    System.out.println(fieldname + " : " + fieldvalue);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        request.setAttribute("message", "Sorry this Servlet only handles file upload request");
    }
```

in **`JSP`** just put code below

```
<form action="uploadtodb" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        User Name:
        <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="123">
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="property_id" value="<%=bean.getproperty_id%>"/>
        <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
```

if you don't want to upload any file the put code as below

**`Servlet`**

```
if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
{

    try
    {
        List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

        for (FileItem item : multiparts)
        {

            if (item.isFormField())
            {
                // Here you will get each and every field that you defined within your form tag
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                System.out.println(fieldname + " : " + fieldvalue);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        request.setAttribute("message", "File Upload Failed due to " + ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
else
{
    request.setAttribute("message", "Unable to parse your request...");
}
```

And just remove input tag with `type="file"` from **`JSP`** file and you are done with it.

What you are doing is for non-multipart request you can't do that with multipart request as it is encrypted...

Comment: Hey I had edited my code plz check it now i had given full code of controller  plz check and help...